Is observing any day by a Reformed Christian tantamount to keeping ceremonial law?
I'm studying Reformed theology. In looking at a collection of Reformed creeds, I'm finding a repeated theme of dividing the Old Testament (OT) commandments into three types:

moral
ceremonial
judicial

This classification to my knowledge has not been articulated in the Scriptures, but seems to have been started by the church fathers (and later formalized by Aquinas) in an effort to discern which of the requirements of the OT law were "binding" on Christians and which were "abrogated" by Jesus' death on the cross.
Leaving out (for the purposes of my questions) the so called "judicial" commandments, I'm seeking to reconcile the historical Reformed theology within its own boundaries on its stance on the division between moral and ceremonial requirements of the law as pertaining to observing a weekly day of rest by Christians.
The 4th Commandment of the Decalogue is usually classified as part of "ceremonial" law. For example, the Geneva Catechism, 1542 (quoted from Ligonier Ministries, “We Believe.”) states regarding the 4th Commandment:

168. M. But does he [God] forbid us any labour on that day [Saturday]?
C. This commandment has a distinct and peculiar reason. In so far as the observation of rest was a part of the ceremonial law; it was abrogated at the coming of Christ.
169. M. Do you say that this commandment respected the Jews only, and was therefore merely temporary?
C. Yes, so far as it was ceremonial.

In other words, "ceremonial" requirements seem to be equated with "abrogated" (non-binding on Christians) as opposed to "moral" requirements that are still binding.
The Geneva Catechism doesn't spell out what nullifies the mandate of the 4th Commandment to observe the original Sabbath for Reformed Christians, but other Reformed confessions do. They seem to follow the interpretation of Paul's words (e.g., Romans 14:5, Galatians 4:10) that teaches that observation of days "as such" is contrary to Christian teaching. For example, the Second Helvetic Confession, 1566 (ibid.) states:

Yet herein we give no place unto the Jewish observation of the day or to any superstitions. For we do not account one day to be holier than another, nor think that mere rest is of itself liked of God.

However, as we read texts of other (later) Reformed creeds, we find that observation of days is not at all abrogated.
For example, on one hand, when it comes to its views on the law of God writ large, the Westminster Confession of Faith, 1646-47 still supports the classification/division of the OT commandments noted earlier (ibid.):


This law, after his fall, continued to be a perfect rule of righteousness; and, as such, was delivered by God upon Mount Sinai, in ten commandments, and written in two tables: the first four commandments containing our duty towards God; and the other six, our duty to man.
Beside this law, commonly called moral, God was pleased to give to the people of Israel, as a church under age, ceremonial laws, containing several typical ordinances, partly of worship, prefiguring Christ, his graces, actions, sufferings, and benefits; and partly, holding forth divers instructions of moral duties. All which ceremonial laws are now abrogated, under the new testament.


However, when addressing the 4th Commandment specifically, the Westminster Confession, 1646-47 (ibid.) states, emphasis supplied:


As it is the law of nature, that, in general, a due proportion of time be set apart for the worship of God; so, in his Word, by a positive, moral, and perpetual commandment binding all men in all ages, he hath particularly appointed one day in seven, for a Sabbath, to be kept holy unto him...


In other words, while maintaining that portions of the Ten Commandment (i.e., the 4th Commandment) are "ceremonial," Westminster Confession (as well as the Savoy Declaration, 1658 and the Second London Baptist Confession, 1677/1689 that followed it) seems to seek to impose its mandate (albeit altering the day which they propose to be kept) on Christians.
So the questions that I have are these:

Is Westminster's stance on the subject of 4th Commandment still an authoritative view in the Reformed churches? If not, what superseded it and how does it differ from Westminster on the subject?
If the 4th Commandment is considered to be "ceremonial," why would it be extended to Reformed Christians as "moral" and binding (even if applied to another day)?
If the 4th Commandment is viewed to be both "ceremonial" and "moral" at the same time (held to be teaching/binding Christians to observe one day per week, just not the original Sabbath), how are Paul's words (e.g., Romans 14:5 or Galatians 4:10) not taken to condemn observation of any other day as the Lord's Day in the same way they are taken to condemn observing the original Sabbath?


You are asking five questions. Ultimately, Paul accepts that some will 'esteem one day above another' and some will 'esteem every day' meaning that some will continue to give honour to a specific day and some will go on (in a position of complete rest and trust) to honour every single day they are given. You are not going to alter these dual perceptions by complicated argument. You have to accept that people's consciences must be respected, whichever side their conscience leads them into. The question (which you seem to be avoiding for some reason) is 'Are Christian believers under law ?'

@NigelJ In both passages referred to in my question Paul is indeed addressing those who continue to keep elements of ceremonial law (in Rom 14:17 "meat and drink" are spoken of, in Gal 5:2 "circumcision" is mentioned). The question is whether to consider the 4th Commandment part of "ceremonial law" or not as it has been historically by the Reformed churches, and if so why not be consistent and abstain from prescribing observation of any day? As far as the loaded "are Christians under the law," I'd ask whether a Christian who worships idols is "in sin?" If so, the Decalogue stands (Rom 6:1-2).

No Christian would worship an idol. Because they are freed from such things. Because they are dead with Christ and alive with Him. Because they are not under the law but under grace.

You seem to be saying that Christians cannot commit sin. That doesn't agree with the Scriptures (e.g., 1 John 1:10-2:1). Paul rebukes both Galatians and Corinthians of sin while referring to them as "saints" and "brethren." While they were "under grace" as Christians, they engaged in sin (as do all humans, Christians or not). Hence Paul's admonitions against adultery /7th Commandment/ in case of Corinthians and against idolatry /1st Commandment/ in case of Galatians). Being "under grace" doesn't absolve Christians of willful future disobedience to God's Law: "go and sin no more" (John 8:11b).

Whosoever is born of God doth not commit sin; for his seed remaineth in him: and he cannot sin, because he is born of God. In this the children of God are manifest, and the children of the devil: whosoever doeth not righteousness is not of God, neither he that loveth not his brother. 1 John 3:9.

Actually, if you read the whole chapter there, that is a statement of rebuke to those who would claim they are sinless. The verse you gave clearly implies that there is a possibility where a Christian "loveth not his brother" while maintaining that he is "sinless." You cannot maintain with the Bible open that a Christian can attain at a "sinless state" while in the body. Otherwise there would be no future glorification to speak of (1 John 3:2). While we are indeed declared sinless owing to Jesus' merit, we aren't precluded from sinning while in the body. I'd read Romans 6 and 1 Corinthians 9.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

I think I shall decline, thank you. Every time I mention a scripture you seem to want to argue against it.

Much homework has been done in order to frame this question, and detailing the various points shows just what a can of worms this subject is. It is said that "a Reformed" stance shows a "repeated theme of dividing the Old Testament commandments into three types - moral, ceremonial and judicial" - but it is also correct to state that "that stance is not articulated in the Scriptures." On the contrary, the Scriptures say such things as

God "blotting out the handwriting of ordinances that was against us,
which was contrary to us, and took it out of the way, nailing it to
the cross... Therefore let no man judge you in meat, or in drink, or
in respect of an holyday, or of the new moon, or of the sabbath, which
are a shadow of things to come; but the body is of Christ." Colossians
2:14-17 A.V.

The modern view is that the Ten Commandments are "the rule of law" that Christians must live by. However, Luther did not have such a clear-cut, simplistic view. It is from the era of the Puritans that insistence comes that it is "the rule of law", Christians must live by, which is taken to mean the moral law as encapsulated by the Ten Commandments, including the seventh day of rest law.
The modern Reformed view does not support the idea that the 'sabbath law' is merely a ceremonial law. It is not enjoined as any kind of a ceremony, or ritual. It goes beyond that, as spelling out requirements for Christians as to what they should, and what they should not do, on what is now called 'Sunday'. They are required to worship God in a particular way not usually engaged in during the rest of the week. They are required to abstain from certain week-day practices (like hanging out washing to dry, or washing dishes). Some even go so far as to insist that, inbetween morning and evening services of worship, they must retire to bed "to rest".
Ah, but already I am behind the times. Most Christians who call themselves 'Reformed' just stick their laundry in a machine and let it do the washing and drying, plus stick dirty dishes in a machine and press a button, not touching those machines again till the next day. This is supposed to still conform to 'sabbath-day' avoidance of work. And many will think nothing of nipping into a local shop for some milk or biscuits if there is none in the church kitchen for their 'sabbath-day' cuppa. Others will play sports on a 'sabbath-day' afternoon, or watch television that evening. The Puritans would be horrified!
This is what happens when strictures are laid down for Christians to observe, yet the scriptures do not deal with those issues. This is what happens when an older view of "the rule of law to live by" is replaced with modern, less demanding, views of such 'law'.
As a Reformed Protestant Christian myself, I see no biblical basis for the general view that the moral law (said to include sabbatarian-type regulations) has to be kept as the Christian's rule of life. My rule of life is the rule of faith. I do not believe that only two-thirds of the law was removed, taken out of our way, when nailed to the cross; that 'the moral law' part remains as a rule of life, as if the rule of faith is insufficient to please God.
My answer to the first, main question is that observing any day by a Reformed Christian, including a 'sabbath-day', can be tantamount to disbelieving Colossians 2:14-17 if reinterpreted to mean clinging on to a degree of legalism in religion. The moral bar Jesus set is far higher than anything in the O.T. law, exposing our hearts and minds, so that only by the grace of God can we receive a cleansed heart and a new mind, in Christ, to live every day in glad and faithful obedience to him.

Your answer equates the "Sabbaths" that Paul was talking about in Colossians 2 with the Sabbath of the Decalogue. The verses in Colossians do speak of ceremonial laws (e.g., Leviticus 23:26-32 speaks of ceremonial Sabbaths). The Colossians passage is parallel to the discussion in Hebrews 10, where Paul talks about the law having "a shadow of good things to come." In context, he is discussing the sacrificial system, not the Decalogue. If you maintain that the Decalogue was nailed to the cross (along with the Sabbath), what is the remaining definition for sin?  What of Romans 7:7,8,12?

@onceDelivered  Ceremonial laws are not "against us" as are God's moral laws. Anyone who has a mind to keep all the ceremonial laws can vigilantly obey them to the nth degree if they are determined enough, as did the religious leaders Jesus condemned (for their legalism). But it is the moral law that everyone fails to keep! Yet legalists claim it was NOT taken out of the way by it being nailed to the cross! What of Col.2:14? Rom.7 shows that law condemns us but only Christ's cross delivers us from its condemnation, thus totally harmonising with Col.2:14.

Your answer still doesn't explain why it is that if a Christian falls into idolatry, commits adultery, or steals there is still a commandment of Decalogue in place to convict him of sin and take him (hopefully) to repentance but if a Christian doesn't keep the Sabbath, there is no commandment to convict him or bring to repentance. According to James (2:10-11), you either keep all 10 or break all of them. Yes, you cannot keep the law perfectly enough to get justified before God. Amen. But have you not dedicated yourself to not committing the sins that the other 9 condemn? Why not the 4th?

@onceDelivered  Your Q is focused on keeping a particular day, a sabbath! That is what you want to know about. I've stuck to your remit. Christians who have been saved by grace have a far heightened horror of sin than ever they did before they repented and experienced God's forgiveness. Now they know what it cost to deal with their sin and they never want to sin again. Yes, they do, but not because they are chained to sin; they're liberated, but James 2 is not 'just' about the Ten C's. We sin if we despise our poor brethren by showing favouritism to rich brethren. It's about the Royal Law.


For what the law could not do, in that it was weak through the flesh, God sending his own Son in the likeness of sinful flesh, and for sin, condemned sin in the flesh: 
That the righteousness of the law might be fulfilled in us, who walk not after the flesh, but after the Spirit. - Romans 8:3-4

All these creeds and canons and what have you are carnal and distracting at best.  Even the Law given by God through Moses is considered as carnal commandments (Heb. 7:16) and a ministry of death and condemnation (2 Corinthians 3:7-9).  And carnal commandments cannot make perfect because they are weak through the flesh.  It is not the fault of the commandment but of the flesh.

For there is verily a disannulling of the commandment going before for the weakness and unprofitableness thereof. For the law made nothing perfect, but the bringing in of a better hope did; by the which we draw nigh unto God. - Hebrews 7:18-19

But we are not in the flesh if we have believed, if we have been born again by grace through faith in the Son of the Living God, if we have been given the promise of the Father, the Holy Spirit of God.  And if we are not in the flesh then we are not under carnal commandment:

But ye are not in the flesh, but in the Spirit, if so be that the Spirit of God dwell in you. Now if any man have not the Spirit of Christ, he is none of his. And if Christ be in you, the body is dead because of sin; but the Spirit is life because of righteousness. - Romans 8:9-10

The letter (of the Law) kills but the Spirit gives life.  The Law is given to reign in and convict flesh.  Those who are in Christ have crucified the flesh, and the writing against them is nailed to the cross, and they have been given a new nature.  This new nature cannot sin because it is born of God; Christ in us, the hope of glory.
When a believer sins (and we all do) it is not committed by the new nature but by the old; not by the Spirit but by the flesh:

This I say then, Walk in the Spirit, and ye shall not fulfil the lust of the flesh. For the flesh lusteth against the Spirit, and the Spirit against the flesh: and these are contrary the one to the other: so that ye cannot do the things that ye would. But if ye be led of the Spirit, ye are not under the law. - Galatians 5:16-18

Whichever dog you feed is the one that wins this fight.  If a believer feels the pressure of the Law, then they are walking in the flesh because it is flesh to which the Law speaks.  The answer is not in keeping the commandments but in walking in the Spirit.

Whosoever is born of God doth not commit sin; for his seed remaineth in him: and he cannot sin, because he is born of God. - 1 John 3:9

This verse must be reckoned with.  Are born again believers instantly sinless or is this the new nature that is in view?  Galatians 5 and Romans 7 indicate that it is the latter.  Putting oneself back under the Law is a re-energizing of the flesh unto condemnation and death:

What shall we say then? Is the law sin? God forbid. Nay, I had not known sin, but by the law: for I had not known lust, except the law had said, Thou shalt not covet. But sin, taking occasion by the commandment, wrought in me all manner of concupiscence. For without the law sin was dead. For I was alive without the law once: but when the commandment came, sin revived, and I died. And the commandment, which was ordained to life, I found to be unto death. For sin, taking occasion by the commandment, deceived me, and by it slew me. - Romans 7:7-11

Whereas Christians are not under law but under grace wherein there is no condemnation, no sin, and no death:

There is therefore now no condemnation to them which are in Christ Jesus, who walk not after the flesh, but after the Spirit. For the law of the Spirit of life in Christ Jesus hath made me free from the law of sin and death. - Romans 8:1-2

It is for freedom that Christ has made us free.  We should honor any or every day as our conscience dictates, informed by both Word and Spirit but beware lest our conviction take on the form of a command to others.  By such we may burden and stumble our brothers with a yoke too heavy to bear.

Deeply edifying, Brother Michael. Instantly up-voted +1. Very much appreciated.

@Mike_Borden You make two statements that are contradictory. You quote Paul who says that he (and any believer) "had not known sin, but by the law" speaking of the Decalogue which he indeed quotes in the same verse (Romans 7:7). I will add that later (v.12) Paul says that "the law is holy, and the commandment holy, and just, and good." You also say that laws given through Moses were "carnal." In Hebrews7:16 the word "carnal" is better translated as "pertaining to the body" (not "sinful") unless you want to make Moses out to be a false prophet which he wasn't (Hebrews3:2)

@Mike Borden While the commandments of the ceremonial law did "pertain to the body," they were not "sinful" as God would not give anyone occasion to sin. Ceremonial law was intended to give "a remembrance again made of sins every year" (Hebrews10:3b) which it did. That system was inadequate to "cleanse" the sinners, but that was not its intent as Hebrews makes clear. We must be wary of basing any doctrine on "freedom" as some use freedom as license to sin (see: 1Pet2:16, Gal5:13, Jud4). What do you say to a Christian in sin (e.g. adultery) who claims he is "under grace" and "not under law"?

@onceDelivered You are correct that carnal does mean "pertaining to the flesh".  This is as true of 1 Cor. 3  as Hebrews 7.  Nowhere does carnal directly equal sinful.  It so happens that, because of Adam, the flesh is weak and corrupted by sin but Jesus, who had no sin, was born under the Law (which is carnal and pertains to the flesh) and could not be condemned by it because His flesh was not sinful.

@onceDelivered The reason the Law is inadequate to cleanse sinners is because it does not remove sin from the flesh nor give the ability to not walk in the flesh.  Christ has given us another way:   Walk in the Spirit.   Just because some misuse "freedom" should not cause us to misuse it in the other direction or shy away from it's proper proclamation.  To a Christian (myself included) who is actively sinning, actively setting their mind on the flesh, actively carnal and claiming "Grace" as the get out of jail free card I would point out that what they are doing is no evidence of grace at all.

I don't disagree with you on the point of Christians abusing grace. The issue remains, how do we know if a Christian's life is moving in the right direction, if he is truly walking in the spirit and being sanctified? If you answer "Is he more and more like Jesus?" you would answer well, but Jesus kept the law of the Decalogue perfectly (including the Sabbath). If you say that it was to "fulfill the law" and not leave us an example to follow. Honestly though, nobody would even argue about Jesus being our example in following the Decalogue (He is of course) if we weren't discussing the Sabbath.

Of course He showed us what "thou shalt not murder" or "thou shalt not commit adultery" truly means. Just look at the Sermon on the Mount (where He clarifies that He didn't come to change the law). It seems that Jesus is taken as an example for "Christian living" in everything but the Sabbath-keeping, which is strange, isn't it? Those who accused Jesus of breaking the Sabbath were also those who condemned and murdered him. I would be careful to go down the same path in thinking that He "broke the 4th Commandment" ("to show us the way") as He obviously could not or would not do such a thing.

@onceDelivered "Know ye not, brethren, (for I speak to them that know the law,) how that the law hath dominion over a man as long as he liveth?".  "Wherefore, my brethren, ye also are become dead to the law by the body of Christ; that ye should be married to another, even to him who is raised from the dead, that we should bring forth fruit unto God.".  The question is:  How is that fruit Law keeping?  Love is the fruit of the Spirit and "Love the fulfills the Law.".   The letter of it kills because the letter of it is toward the flesh.  The Spirit gives life because it fulfills the Law.

@onceDelivered  How do I spiritually keep the command "Thou shalt not murder"?  It is by loving my neighbor.  If I love him in the Spirit I will never murder him in the flesh.  If I love God with all my everything, I will never have another God before Him, etc.  Although Jesus kept the Law in His flesh, if He is an example to us it is not that for we cannot keep the Law that way; our flesh is subject to sin.  His example to us is walking in the Spirit.  It is also His empowering within us.  "But ye are not in the flesh, but in the Spirit, if so be that the Spirit of God dwell in you."

I am not sure the Reformed opinion on the Lord’s day (the Christian version of a kind of Sabbath) is completely agreed upon by all different Reformed groups, just like the idea of tithes is not agreed upon by all, but as I agree with Luther’s view on your question I will answer it that way. Luther approached the topic as you mentioned: ‘both ceremonial and moral’. That observing a certain day was fine but observing another day would also be fine.
My own observation, not mentioned by Luther here, is that obviously one can’t fully separate moral, legal and judicial in the Mosaic covenant because breaking the Sabbath merely by ‘picking up some sticks’ resulted in death as a capital punishment (Numbers 15:32-36). The severity of the punishment was judicial and could also be considered ceremonial or symbolic in that it symbolized the curse under the covenant of works.  Furthermore, although the Pharisees did question the behavior of the disciples when they ‘plucked ears of corn’ (so much labor being involved!), showing that at least some legalist practices were maintained by the Jews even to the time of Christ, I doubt anyone was stoned to death by doing a little homework after Sunday school class post Jesus (the period of Christianity). The point: the obviously strict adherence to the Sabbath in that original Mosaic sense is not followed by anyone today, even if it was followed at some point in history, lending more to the idea that some measure of symbolism was attached to it, as well as retaining some measure of the strictness of the laws commanding all the ceremonies in Mosaic period.  Did a person not die if they entered the holy of holies? This was ceremonial, judicial and moral as were many other parts of the Mosaic Law for the Jews.  Moral in one's duty to revere God, judicial in the death penalty, ceremonial in the symbolic expression of being alienated to God and only the High Priest being able to enter with blood once a year.
But back to the main topic, the Sabbath as understood by the Reformers of whom Luther is first rate.
Luther thought the separation of the Mosaic covenant into Legal, Judicial and Ceremonial was basically not that useful, though it had a purpose to some extent. Furthermore, Luther believed the Mosaic Laws were technically only for the Jews and that only the moral commands were applicable to both Jews and non-Jews by virtue of their common natural conscience.
Here Luther clearly states some ceremonial Laws were mingled into the Ten Commandments. (He thought Moses may have not allowed any images under the first commandment and he definitely thought, without any doubt, that the Sabbath was ‘partly ceremonial’. Don’t misunderstand Luther here, he was not an antinomian, he is simply arguing that the Jewish Sabbath was not applicable to Gentiles as it was written, though the spirit of it, the need to rest and worship, is still a command in the sense that it corresponds to the natural law in our freedom from the law of Moses).

Yes, you say, that is perhaps true with respect to the ceremonial and
the judicial law, that is, what Moses teaches about the external order
of worship or of government. But the decalogue, that is, the Ten
Commandments, are not abrogated. There is nothing of ceremonial and
judicial law in them. I answer: I know very well that this is an old
and common distinction, but it is not an intelligent one. For out of
the Ten Commandments flow and depend all the other commandments and
the whole of Moses. (Luther’s Works vol 40 page 92)
Again one can prove it from the third commandment that Moses does not
pertain to Gentiles and Christians. For Paul [Col. 2:16] and the New
Testament [Matt. 12:1–12; John 5:16; 7:22–23; 9:14–16] abolish the
sabbath, to show us that the sabbath was given to the Jews alone, for
whom it is a stern commandment. The prophets referred to it too, that
the sabbath of the Jews would be abolished. For Isaiah says in the
last chapter, “When the Savior comes, then such will be the time, one
sabbath after the other, one month after the other,” etc. This is as
though he were trying to say, “It will be the sabbath every day, and
the people will be such that they make no distinction between days.
For in the New Testament the sabbath is annihilated as regards the
crude external observance, for every day is a holy day,” etc. (Luther's Works vol 35 pages 165-166)

Here again Luther clearly says what the natural law requires regarding the Sabbath (you can use the somewhat artificial division of moral law here):

It is not necessary to observe the sabbath or Sunday because of Moses’
commandment. Nature also shows and teaches that one must now and then
rest a day, so that man and beast may be refreshed. This natural
reason Moses also recognized in his sabbath law, for he places the
sabbath under man, as also Christ does (Matt. 12[:1ff.] and Mark
3[:2ff.]). For where it is kept for the sake of rest alone, it is
clear that he who does not need rest may break the sabbath and rest on
some other day, as nature allows. The sabbath is also to be kept for
the purpose of preaching and hearing the Word of God (Luther's Works vol 40 page 98).

Here Luther argues the other side and defends special days, not as a law that binds consciences but for other uses:

Here someone may say: “If the Galatians sinned in observing days and
seasons, why is it not sinful for you to do the same?” I reply: We
observe the Lord’s Day, Christmas, Easter, and similar holidays in a
way that is completely free. We do not burden consciences with these
observances; nor do we teach, as did the false apostles and as do the
papists, that they are necessary for justification or that we can make
satisfaction for our sins through them. But their purpose is that
everything be done in the church in an orderly way and without
confusion, so that external harmony may not be disturbed; for in the
spirit we have another kind of harmony. Thus it happened once that
Victor, the Roman pontiff, excommunicated all the churches of Asia for
no other reason than that they celebrated Easter at another time than
the Church of Rome observed it. Irenaeus rebukes this action of
Victor’s, and it was surely worthy of rebuke. For it was the utmost
madness to hand the churches of the East over to the devil on account
of such a trifle. Therefore this knowledge about the observance of
days and seasons was rare, even among great men. Jerome did not have
it, and Augustine would not have understood it if he had not been
troubled and provoked by the Pelagians.
Most of all, however, we observe such holidays to preserve the
ministry of the Word, so that the people may gather on certain days
and at certain seasons to hear the Word, to learn to know God, to have
Communion, to pray together for every need, and to thank God for His
spiritual and temporal blessings. And I believe that this was the
chief reason why the fathers instituted the Lord’s Day, Easter,
Pentecost, etc.
(Luther's Works vol 26, Lectures on Galatians (1535), pages 411-412)


Thanks for this selection of Luther's quotes. While I respect Luther's authority very much, his thinking was in some ways still tainted by the teaching and practices of the church he used to belong to. Even in one of your quotes, he calls what in fact is the 4th Commandment to be 3rd in number which is how the Roman Church distorted the Decalogue (having gotten rid of the 2nd Commandment in lieu of their adoption and normalization of idol worship). He likewise misunderstood that the Sabbath was "given to the Jews." Was marriage given to the Jews only as well? Genesis 2 has the answer.

@onceDelivered -  Luther considered the entire Mosaic Law to be only for the Jews only but where it overlapped with conscience, to which it did a great deal, it was applicable to the whole world. So basically to reduce the answer a great deal Luther thought you should take some rest and worship God once a week. You should also honor marriage per  Genesis 2, not because it was part of any Mosaic legislation but because it was a natural law.

Genesis 2 doesn't say God blessed "one day per week and sanctified it" any more than it says that humans can define marriage in any way they want. Can a Christian engage in adultery or same-sex marriage and observe any day of the week other than the day that God set apart for it in the beginning? Sure. But God already identified those acts as sin (as expressed in Genesis 2, in the Decalogue, and elsewhere in the Pentateuch). Gentiles who seek to get rid of the moral law of God (the Decalogue) are well advised to not follow the Jews in unbelief and rejection of God. (Romans 11:13-24)

@onceDelivered - Interesting idea I have actually never heard this view before. It sounds like you think the exact day matters. I don’t think that generally fits the reformed view but at the same time, such a belief, in and of itself does not really exlude one from faith in the gospel either, in the reformed view. So this would be considerd a non-essential area that one can have their own view on. If on the other hand one insited that people obeserve an exact day, otherwise they could be damned, then and only then would a reformed view consider that person without Christ.

I do appreciate the brotherly embrace! Christians treat the 4th Commandment as though it were part of the handwriting of ordinances that was "nailed to the cross" while it is clearly one of the commandments that was inscribed on the tablets of stone (and now on our hearts) by the very finger of God. It seems to me that every commandment deemed "essential enough" to be placed inside the ark of the covenant ought to be "essential enough" for us to be careful about sinning against... Some writing of the law was placed within and some without... We can misprioratize if we fail to note that...

Short of giving a simple/short answer, I will highlight several points that make this a difficult question. I realize this is a question that touches upon something Christians have struggled to come together on over centuries if not millennia. Those age-old disagreements of course will not be settled in a series of posts. If we were to liken our attempts to find the right answer to difficult (but valid) questions of Biblical teaching to answering questions on a multiple-choice test (I think that is an apt analogy), I see my asking the questions as an attempt at zeroing in on the possible right answer(s) by eliminating the answer choices that could be clearly identified as "invalid" in light of the testimony of the Scriptures...
I tried to organize my post below by numbering my "questions," but my questions often come in pairs or even triplets because of the implications of possible answers that could be given in response. I realize that makes it more difficult to address a specific question to any responder who wishes to engage with a question, but I feel that it was unreasonable to number each question as there are so many. Instead of the number of a question, I'd refer to them as to a "group" of questions, as I anticipate those follow-up questions as "connected" and requiring a response as the initial question in that group is being answered...
Further, I intentionally limited my question to Reformed Christians because in my mind our group is conscience-bound (or at least "professionally" so) to uphold the Sola Scriptura principle. Obviously, when a Christian brings in categories like "Church authority," "Church history," or "Church tradition," the conversation must necessarily expand to include the discussion of legitimacy of such a change to the source of doctrine/practice before any given point of teaching is discussed on its merits. Hence, when I use term "Christian" below, I mean a Reformed Christian who is trying to maintain a scripturally-sound dynamic of teaching and its reflection in practical life.
First, on the use of the term "ceremonial."
There is probably going to be an agreement here that a ceremonial prescription is a visible action/ritual which prefigures or illustrates a reality that is invisible or spiritual. In a limited sense, all Christians keep certain ceremonial commandments/institutions. For example, baptism and the Lord's Supper can both be said to be "ceremonial" and yet are observed nearly universally by Christians with no objection given on the grounds of the ceremonial nature of those institutions. (Of course most Christians would note that those two institutions are established in the text of the New Testament. Nevertheless, the point remains that "ceremonial" institutions aren't inherently a taboo for Christians, if someone wants to pursue that as a sharp distinction between the "Old-" and "New-" Testament teaching.)
Further, when it comes to observation of days, there is no shortage of "ceremoniality" if we listen to the reasoning given by each person who advocates that Christians ought to observe certain days and argue against observation of others (whether it be weekly or annually).
Question 1: Is it then legitimate to refer to such widely-accepted-by-churches "ceremonial" institutions as simply "symbolic" to remove the stigmatizing "ceremonial" label?
Perhaps there is a case to be made there. Maybe the question to ask is which "ceremonies" Christians are taught to observe, and not whether they are taught to observe "ceremonies."
If we accept that there are "ceremonies" for Christians to observe and that observation of days is in some sense "definitionally" ceremonial, as far as pertinent institutions given in the OT scriptures, there are at least two options possible.

Every observation of a day is unacceptable (or even forbidden) to a Christian — i.e., a post-cross believer — regardless of the day and reason given for the observation;
Observation of certain days is acceptable (and even commanded) to a Christian.

On this first point, one must make a commitment one way or the other as one cannot maintain both as attempted by some who for the sake of argument say that they oppose elevating one day over others and then do single out one day for matters spiritual on a weekly basis. If a Christian wants to maintain that to a Christian "all days are alike," that Christian will also then have to recon with the issue of why he/she chooses to go to church, have communal worship, have spiritual devotions and Bible lessons etc. on one day and not the other and what scriptural basis he/she has for making that choice.
Question 2: If Christians maintain that it makes absolutely no difference when all those things take place, what would it do to organized church life? If some Christians want to have communal worship on Wednesdays and other on Fridays, would anyone be able to scripturally maintain that the matter could be decided by a vote whose outcome would be then equally acceptable to God?
It's hard to see how the first position can be maintained as a matter of church practice as well. Perhaps that's why there aren't that many regular Christian weekday morning worship services out there.
Question 3: Moreover, in light of the fact that there is a Decalogue commandment that prescribes observation of a certain day, would not a Christian who chooses to observe a day that is other than the original Sabbath on a weekly basis effectively seek to observe but another "ceremonial" Sabbath on another day? Whether the answer is yes or no, the answerer will be forced to abandon the first position ("all days are alike") and give rationale for the change of the weekly day of worship thus effectively embracing the second position.
The second position seems more consistent with both common sense and what is observed in weekly lives of Christians as most of us do come together to have communal worship, have spiritual devotions and Bible lessons etc. on a certain day on a weekly basis (and not on random days of the week as the first position would propose Christians would). The second position can be maintained in two ways:

Observation of the original Sabbath (as prescribed by the 4th Commandment of the Decalogue);
Observation of another day — in place of the original Sabbath (as prescribed by authority other than the Scriptures as an explicit mandate for such a change is missing from both the Old- and New-Testament text, for "Surely the Lord God will do nothing, but he revealeth his secret unto his servants the prophets." (Amos 3:7). In fact, when the change of the covenant (to which oft-quoted in connection to the supposed "abolishing of the original Sabbath" Hebrews 10:16,17 is said to refer to) was initially announced by the OT prophets centuries before it was to take place, there was no change to the law predicted. Instead, the Lord said "I will put my law in their inward parts, and write it in their hearts" (Jeremiah 31:33b). What was to change at the "time of the reformation" (Hebrews 9:10b)? Clearly the law to be written on the hearts of NT-era believers was not the ceremonial law that was destined for abrogation according to Hebrews 7-10 — as the sacrificial system whereby sacrifices would serve as but an annual reminder of sins pointed to the one Sacrifice "[b]y the which will we are sanctified through the offering of the body of Jesus Christ once for all" (Hebrews 10:10). We would pose that the law that was to be written on the hearts was the Decalogue whose immutability for NT-era believers is in fact explicitly stated by Paul (e.g., Romans 7:7,8,12) and James (2:10-12).

If observation of the original Sabbath cannot be "implicated" and considered as "unacceptable" for the NT-era Christians (as we've tried to show by reasoning above, a weekly day of worship still is maintained by Christians no matter their choice or the argument given to support it), Christians have a choice to either keep the original Sabbath or replace it with another day.
Rationales given to replace the original Sabbath usually fall into several categories that can be shown to be connected by a certain common thread that seeks to "bundle" the original Sabbath with the "old covenant" (portions of the discussion of ceremonial law writ large in Hebrews 7-10 and/or parallel passage from Colossians (2:14-17) are usually quoted to support the idea of the original Sabbath "having been abolished" as far as Christians are concerned):

The original Sabbath was "given to Jewish people for a specific purpose and time period that is now in the past" (as opposed to being given to humanity as a whole for a specific purpose for all time); — though an exception is sometimes made by Christians who seek to maintain that Jews may continue to keep the original Sabbath due to their ethnic heritage
The original Sabbath was but a ritual/ceremonial "shadow" that was to prefigure (in the OT era) a reality that was to come (and did come) in the life, death, and ministry of Jesus Christ;
The original Sabbath was "fulfilled" by Jesus Christ making it unnecessary (or even forbidden) for (non-Jewish) Christians to observe.

I'm struggling to reconcile the first two points with the Genesis account of the instruction given to the yet unfallen/undivided humanity. In Genesis 2:2,3, we are told:

And on the seventh day God ended his work which he had made; and he rested on the seventh day from all his work which he had made. And God blessed the seventh day, and sanctified it: because that in it he had rested from all his work which God created and made.

Similarly, after Eve was created, and Adam had acknowledged that she was in fact "help meet for him" (as God had indeed intended according to Genesis 2:18b), in Genesis 2:24 we are told:

Therefore shall a man leave his father and his mother, and shall cleave unto his wife: and they shall be one flesh.

When Jesus confronted the Pharisees of his day on the subject of marriage, He corrected their understanding by referring them back to the pattern given "in the beginning" (Matthew 19:4-9, emphasis supplied):

And he answered and said unto them, Have ye not read, that he which made them at the beginning made them male and female, And said, For this cause shall a man leave father and mother, and shall cleave to his wife: and they twain shall be one flesh? Wherefore they are no more twain, but one flesh. What therefore God hath joined together, let not man put asunder. They say unto him, Why did Moses then command to give a writing of divorcement, and to put her away? He saith unto them, Moses because of the hardness of your hearts suffered you to put away your wives: but from the beginning it was not so. And I say unto you, Whosoever shall put away his wife, except it be for fornication, and shall marry another, committeth adultery: and whoso marrieth her which is put away doth commit adultery.

If we note carefully how Jesus in defending the 7th Commandment counters his adversaries, we will find that He goes back to Genesis 2 (not Exodus 20, or Deuteronomy 5) by effectively arguing from that which was given "at the beginning."
Question 4: If Jesus so defended the 7th Commandment (which defense I trust most Christians would heartily endorse), what would preclude us as Christians from pursuing the same reasoning in regard to the 4th Commandment, i.e., if God "blessed the seventh day, and sanctified it" (as He did heterosexual marriage) at the beginning (before the fall and before humanity was divided into Jews and gentiles), would that not make the original Sabbath worthy of defense in the same way Christians seek to defend the original marriage? And if Christians choose to defend the latter and and not the former by using the "Genesis" argument, why would the "Genesis" argument not work in defense of the 4th Commandment in the same way it does in case of the 7th?
As far as Sabbath being given as a "symbol," a "figure," or a "shadow of things to come" (as Colossians 2:17a is often quoted) there are a couple of problematic dimensions to that reasoning.
Question 5: Given the Genesis 2 account, what would be the rationale to pursue two different approaches to two institutions given therein? Would it not be logical to take all of the institutions given there as "symbols?" And if so, would not both be symbols in the same way? If not, than why not be consistent and see both the original Sabbath and marriage as shadows of things to come? And if both are indeed taken to prefigure greater, "spiritual" realities not yet fully "consummated" (the Sabbath symbolizing "'resting' in God's salvation" that is not yet "complete," 1 John 3:2 and marriage foreshadowing the glorious union between God and his people that is awaiting its ultimate fulfillment in the Marriage Supper of the Lamb, Revelation 19:6-9) what would be the reasoning behind upholding the institute of the original marriage for Christians while arguing for replacing the original Sabbath with another day for their earthly sojourn?
As far as Jesus' "fulfilling" the Sabbath, while I can be persuaded to conditionally accept that phraseology, the question I have is what its implications are for the weekly day of rest for a Christian.
Question 6: If we hold (as most Christians do) that marriage is indeed a "symbol" of the union between Jesus as the Bridegroom and the Church as his bride, does it therefore mean that people are free to change or redefine marriage in whatever way they want (given that marriage between people is "merely" a symbol of a higher reality)? Why is it that Christians would argue that the original pattern of marriage between a man and a woman is indeed sacred and unchangeable from its original Genesis 2 state, at least until the time of the resurrection whereby we'll be made like angels who "neither marry nor [...] given in marriage," Matthew 22:30 (not in the least in lieu of its spiritual symbolism), but the fact that the original Sabbath is a symbol of a greater reality means that the Sabbath ought to be abandoned for another day?

+1. My personal view that I did not put in my own answer is simply all days are the same but God will manage to arrange a day for me to rest on a weekly basis because he cares for me, and symbolicly the Sabbath is ultimately a symbol that we must think of holiness as a day where we do no work because we find rest when being justified apart from works, a rest I have entered into. But this would be too complicated to explain in an answer and more like my own opinions of sorts, nevertheless this is what my conscience accepts.  I find your analysis serious and honest and well articulated.
